# How to deal with the "AMD breaks Blender" questions?

Tags: discussion

You've probably noticed the huge influx of questions, where (often very new) users encounter glitches in Blender (maybe?) caused by the AMD driver issues.

The problem with these questions is that while I definitely have no idea how to address them (since I do not know what exactly causes these problems) I am also not comfortable flagging them as duplicates or off-topic (since I do not know what causes them).

I'm also not happy with just ignoring them since they clutter the website and the people who write these questions seem to be genuinely looking for help.

Any advice on how to deal with these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you mark them as duplicate of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra/204303#204303), if it is the same problem. Should it be a different one then vote to close with a "community-specific reason" and select that it should be reported on the bug tracker.

Comment: The problem is that some of the screenshots look vastly different from the one in the question you've linked. Example: (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206219/red-purple-light-in-rendered-mode). So while I suspect your answer would be fitting, I do not know for sure. 

Also is it smart to suggest that such incidents should be reported on the Blender bug tracker? Is there anything the Blender-devs can do about this issue?

Comment: To figure out whether or not devs can do something about it requires triage on the bug tracker. In this particular case the GPU is below the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) and thus not officially supported. Graphics glitches or even crashes can occur due to issue with the graphics drivers. Reporting this on the bug tracker would not be helpful. Hence I've written a guide [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports/173685#173685)  that is also linked when a bug report gets closed with "report on the bug tracker".

Comment: Totally concur. There are currently 67 questions linked to the dupe QA . https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/204297?lq=1   To reinforce answer above When they are obviously a duplicate (only an outline in material view) please get the ball rolling and vote to close as dupe ASAP , rather than commenting. (or worse answering..)  using info from dupe answers.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Nlqjfj1lL5A?t=2209  potential update on this?

Comment: @AllenSimpson It is a workaround for the issues (see [T82856](https://developer.blender.org/T82856)).